# correlation, get rid of group effect

Tags: correlation, mixed-model, experiment-design, factor-analysis

I am doing my data analysis, but meet problems, don't know how to get rid of the effect of group... Description as follows: Two variables 'should' have a strong relationship; the trial was done in three weeks, and the factor 'week' have a significant effect on one of the tested variable. Like the graph shows:

[image]

If we do the test of each seperate week, the correlation is strong; if we do the test of all dataset, the correlation is weak. So is there any way to get rid of the week effect? Thanks!

Comment: Simpson's paradox?

Comment: Hi Arya, thanks good to know :-)

Comment: But is there are methods that I can apply? Like to analysis within the group?